# Sort function clips with custom comparator CLIPS

Tags: clips

the sorting function using my comparator gives me this sorting 
(Fact-57 Fact-58 Fact-59 Fact-60).

The facts to sort are:
[image: Sorting]

COMPARATOR:

```
(deffunction MAIN::rating-sort (?f1 ?f2)
   (if (< (fact-slot-value ?f1 sum-certainties) (fact-slot-value ?f2 sum-certainties)) then return TRUE
   else (if (> (fact-slot-value ?f1 sum-certainties) (fact-slot-value ?f2 sum-certainties)) then return FALSE
        else (if (> (fact-slot-value ?f1 total-price) (fact-slot-value ?f2 total-price)) then return TRUE
             else (if (< (fact-slot-value ?f1 total-price) (fact-slot-value ?f2 total-price)) then return FALSE
                  else return FALSE)))))
```

CODE:

```
(bind ?facts (find-all-facts ((?f alternative)) TRUE))
   (bind ?facts (sort rating-sort ?facts))
   (printout t ?facts crlf)
```

I can't understand why it doesn't order them...

AN EXPECTED RESULT: (Fact-57 Fact-59 Fact-58 Fact-60)

Comment: The code you've posted works correctly for me. You need to include a fully reproducible example that includes all the code needed to demonstrate the issue. Include the text of the code, not screen shots.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort a set of facts CLIPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58026686/sort-a-set-of-facts-clips)